# Basic picturebox error

Tags: vb.net, vba, picturebox

I want to add a .gif image to a picturebox.
I want user to choose image from a variety of images of different pixels.
if I use

```
    picturebox1.image = image.fromfile("E:\ship1")
```

then there is no option available of imagelayout unlike backgroundimage.
because of different images pixel only half of image is displayed in my picturebox size.
I don't want to change my picturebox size because in the  game that i am working on, it can cause problems.
If i use

```
    picturebox.backgroundimage = image.fromfile("E:\ship1")
```

but then .gif would not show its animation.
Any suggestion for solution apart from changing size of picturebox cause that would be the last thing to do

Comment: load the file to an Image and resize it to the desired H and W

Comment: @plutonix I cant resize the images's height or width bacause after resizing it loses its transparent background. Or i didnt get your solution plzz elaborate

Comment: You can work with `SizeMode` property of the PictureBox control. Set it to `CenterImage` will center the image in your control, without resizing it.

Comment: set sizemode as StretchImage of picturebox.